# Quantity Validation

Tags: php, mysql

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $DATE = $_POST['date'];
    $PRODUCT_ID = $_POST['product_id'];
    $BRANCH_ID = $_POST['branch_id'];
    $PROD_PURCHASE_PRICE = $_POST['product_unit'];
    $QUANTITY = $_POST['quantity'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `inventory_master` WHERE `PRODUCT_ID` = '$PRODUCT_ID' AND `BRANCH_ID` = '$BRANCH_ID'";
    $inventory_distribution_details = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_assoc();
    if(isset($inventory_distribution_details)){
        if($inventory_distribution_details['QUANTITY'] >= $QUANTITY){
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO inventory_distribution(DATE,PRODUCT_ID,BRANCH_ID,PROD_PURCHASE_PRICE,QUANTITY) VALUES('$DATE','$PRODUCT_ID','$BRANCH_ID','$PROD_PURCHASE_PRICE','$QUANTITY')";
            $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
            if ($result2 === TRUE) {
                $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
            }else{
                $error = array('title' => "Error occured. Please try again.", 'icon' => "warning");
            }
        }else{
            $error = array('title' => "Quantity should be not be greater than ".$inventory_distribution_details['QUANTITY'], 'icon' => "warning");
        }
    }else{
        $error = array('title' => "Product not available in Inventory", 'icon' => "warning");
    }
}
```

Inventory distribution quantity should not be greater than inventory master quantity then only insert record in database.
Inventory master quantity = 30
I'm inserting two records of inventory distribution quantity with 10 and 25.
It has to show error 
But here the record is inserting in database.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: What, *exactly*, is your question?

Comment: `WHERE QUANTITY >= $QUANTITYLIMIT` I think in select query! and than insert into db. @JayBlanchard this is the question I think *Inventory distribution quantity should not be greater than inventory master quantity*

Comment: your question is not clar.

Comment: and there is a huge security issue inside your cdoe